# Error deleting OneToMany element with Cascade.ALL and orphanRemoval=true

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'm trying to delete an element of the property deliveryNotes from work but when I look at the log of jpa, I only see selects and any delete DML statement.

I already have another collections in work like orders and it works well and it is defined the same way as delivery notes.

What could it be?

**WorkBean.java**

```
 public void deleteDeliveryNote(DeliveryNote note) {
        work.removeDeliveryNote(note);
        try {
            work = workSvc.save(work);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0}{1}", new Object[]{Messages.getString(sesBean.getLocale(), "dnt_errdeleting"), e.getMessage()});
        }
    }
```

**Work.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_work")
public class Work {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<DeliveryNote> deliveryNotes;
    ...

    public void addDeliveryNote(DeliveryNote note) {
        deliveryNotes.add(note);
        note.setWork(this);
    }

    public void removeDeliveryNote(DeliveryNote note) {
        note.setWork(null);
        deliveryNotes.remove(note);
    }
}
```

**WorkService.java**

```
@Stateless
public class WorkService {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Work save(Work work) {

        if (work.getId() == null) {
            this.em.persist(work);
            return work;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(work);
        }
    }
}
```

**DeliveryNote.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_deliveryNote")
public class DeliveryNote extends BaseEntity {
...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;

        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);

        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof BaseEntity)) {
            return false;
        }

        BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) obj;
        return id != null && id.equals(other.getId());
    }
...
```

**JPA log queries after saving work**

```
19:35:31,354 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select work0_.id as id1_15_1_, work0_.version as version2_15_1_, work0_.date_u as date_u3_15_1_, work0_.date_c as date_c4_15_1_, work0_.date_d as date_d5_15_1_, work0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_15_1_, work0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_15_1_, work0_.idUser_u as idUser_14_15_1_, work0_.address as address8_15_1_, work0_.code as code9_15_1_, work0_.idCompany as idCompa15_15_1_, work0_.description as descrip10_15_1_, work0_.end as end11_15_1_, work0_.init as init12_15_1_, work0_.name as name13_15_1_, work0_.idWorkType as idWorkT16_15_1_, contacts1_.idWork as idWork11_16_3_, contacts1_.id as id1_16_3_, contacts1_.id as id1_16_0_, contacts1_.version as version2_16_0_, contacts1_.date_u as date_u3_16_0_, contacts1_.date_c as date_c4_16_0_, contacts1_.date_d as date_d5_16_0_, contacts1_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_16_0_, contacts1_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_16_0_, contacts1_.idUser_u as idUser_u9_16_0_, contacts1_.description as descript8_16_0_, contacts1_.idPerson as idPerso10_16_0_, contacts1_.idWork as idWork11_16_0_ from t_work work0_ left outer join t_workContact contacts1_ on work0_.id=contacts1_.idWork where work0_.id=?
19:35:31,382 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_13_1_, user0_.version as version2_13_1_, user0_.date_u as date_u3_13_1_, user0_.date_c as date_c4_13_1_, user0_.date_d as date_d5_13_1_, user0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_13_1_, user0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_13_1_, user0_.idUser_u as idUser_10_13_1_, user0_.password as password8_13_1_, user0_.idPerson as idPerso11_13_1_, user0_.username as username9_13_1_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_0_, userroles1_.version as version2_14_0_, userroles1_.idRole as idRole3_14_0_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_0_ from t_user user0_ left outer join t_userRole userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.idUser where user0_.id=?
19:35:31,404 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_2_1_, role0_.version as version2_2_1_, role0_.name as name3_2_1_, userrols1_.idRole as idRole3_14_3_, userrols1_.id as id1_14_3_, userrols1_.id as id1_14_0_, userrols1_.version as version2_14_0_, userrols1_.idRole as idRole3_14_0_, userrols1_.idUser as idUser4_14_0_ from a_role role0_ left outer join t_userRole userrols1_ on role0_.id=userrols1_.idRole where role0_.id=?
19:35:31,419 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_10_0_, person0_.version as version2_10_0_, person0_.date_u as date_u3_10_0_, person0_.date_c as date_c4_10_0_, person0_.date_d as date_d5_10_0_, person0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_10_0_, person0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_10_0_, person0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_10_0_, person0_.email as email8_10_0_, person0_.firstname as firstnam9_10_0_, person0_.lastname as lastnam10_10_0_, person0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_10_0_ from t_person person0_ where person0_.id=?
19:35:31,437 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_2_1_, role0_.version as version2_2_1_, role0_.name as name3_2_1_, userrols1_.idRole as idRole3_14_3_, userrols1_.id as id1_14_3_, userrols1_.id as id1_14_0_, userrols1_.version as version2_14_0_, userrols1_.idRole as idRole3_14_0_, userrols1_.idUser as idUser4_14_0_ from a_role role0_ left outer join t_userRole userrols1_ on role0_.id=userrols1_.idRole where role0_.id=?
19:35:31,455 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_13_1_, user0_.version as version2_13_1_, user0_.date_u as date_u3_13_1_, user0_.date_c as date_c4_13_1_, user0_.date_d as date_d5_13_1_, user0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_13_1_, user0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_13_1_, user0_.idUser_u as idUser_10_13_1_, user0_.password as password8_13_1_, user0_.idPerson as idPerso11_13_1_, user0_.username as username9_13_1_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_0_, userroles1_.version as version2_14_0_, userroles1_.idRole as idRole3_14_0_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_0_ from t_user user0_ left outer join t_userRole userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.idUser where user0_.id=?
19:35:31,474 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_10_0_, person0_.version as version2_10_0_, person0_.date_u as date_u3_10_0_, person0_.date_c as date_c4_10_0_, person0_.date_d as date_d5_10_0_, person0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_10_0_, person0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_10_0_, person0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_10_0_, person0_.email as email8_10_0_, person0_.firstname as firstnam9_10_0_, person0_.lastname as lastnam10_10_0_, person0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_10_0_ from t_person person0_ where person0_.id=?
19:35:31,492 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_13_1_, user0_.version as version2_13_1_, user0_.date_u as date_u3_13_1_, user0_.date_c as date_c4_13_1_, user0_.date_d as date_d5_13_1_, user0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_13_1_, user0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_13_1_, user0_.idUser_u as idUser_10_13_1_, user0_.password as password8_13_1_, user0_.idPerson as idPerso11_13_1_, user0_.username as username9_13_1_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_3_, userroles1_.id as id1_14_0_, userroles1_.version as version2_14_0_, userroles1_.idRole as idRole3_14_0_, userroles1_.idUser as idUser4_14_0_ from t_user user0_ left outer join t_userRole userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.idUser where user0_.id=?
19:35:31,511 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_10_0_, person0_.version as version2_10_0_, person0_.date_u as date_u3_10_0_, person0_.date_c as date_c4_10_0_, person0_.date_d as date_d5_10_0_, person0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_10_0_, person0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_10_0_, person0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_10_0_, person0_.email as email8_10_0_, person0_.firstname as firstnam9_10_0_, person0_.lastname as lastnam10_10_0_, person0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_10_0_ from t_person person0_ where person0_.id=?
19:35:31,531 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_5_0_, company0_.version as version2_5_0_, company0_.date_u as date_u3_5_0_, company0_.date_c as date_c4_5_0_, company0_.date_d as date_d5_5_0_, company0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_5_0_, company0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_5_0_, company0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_5_0_, company0_.email as email8_5_0_, company0_.name as name9_5_0_, company0_.nif as nif10_5_0_, company0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_5_0_ from t_company company0_ where company0_.id=?
19:35:31,549 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select worktype0_.id as id1_4_1_, worktype0_.version as version2_4_1_, worktype0_.description as descript3_4_1_, worktype0_.name as name4_4_1_, works1_.idWorkType as idWorkT16_15_3_, works1_.id as id1_15_3_, works1_.id as id1_15_0_, works1_.version as version2_15_0_, works1_.date_u as date_u3_15_0_, works1_.date_c as date_c4_15_0_, works1_.date_d as date_d5_15_0_, works1_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_15_0_, works1_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_15_0_, works1_.idUser_u as idUser_14_15_0_, works1_.address as address8_15_0_, works1_.code as code9_15_0_, works1_.idCompany as idCompa15_15_0_, works1_.description as descrip10_15_0_, works1_.end as end11_15_0_, works1_.init as init12_15_0_, works1_.name as name13_15_0_, works1_.idWorkType as idWorkT16_15_0_ from a_workType worktype0_ left outer join t_work works1_ on worktype0_.id=works1_.idWorkType where worktype0_.id=?
19:35:31,590 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_5_0_, company0_.version as version2_5_0_, company0_.date_u as date_u3_5_0_, company0_.date_c as date_c4_5_0_, company0_.date_d as date_d5_5_0_, company0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_5_0_, company0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_5_0_, company0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_5_0_, company0_.email as email8_5_0_, company0_.name as name9_5_0_, company0_.nif as nif10_5_0_, company0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_5_0_ from t_company company0_ where company0_.id=?
19:35:31,607 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_5_0_, company0_.version as version2_5_0_, company0_.date_u as date_u3_5_0_, company0_.date_c as date_c4_5_0_, company0_.date_d as date_d5_5_0_, company0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_5_0_, company0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_5_0_, company0_.idUser_u as idUser_12_5_0_, company0_.email as email8_5_0_, company0_.name as name9_5_0_, company0_.nif as nif10_5_0_, company0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_5_0_ from t_company company0_ where company0_.id=?
19:35:31,626 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_6_1_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_u as date_u3_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_c as date_c4_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_d as date_d5_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_u as idUser_11_6_1_, deliveryno0_.endTime as endTime8_6_1_, deliveryno0_.init as init9_6_1_, deliveryno0_.initTime as initTim10_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUserAux as idUserA13_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idWork as idWork14_6_1_, lines1_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_3_, lines1_.id as id1_7_3_, lines1_.id as id1_7_0_, lines1_.version as version2_7_0_, lines1_.amount as amount3_7_0_, lines1_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines1_.description as descript4_7_0_ from t_deliveryNote deliveryno0_ left outer join t_deliveryNoteLine lines1_ on deliveryno0_.id=lines1_.idDeliveryNote where deliveryno0_.id=?
19:35:31,693 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_0_1_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_0_1_, deliveryno0_.name as name3_0_1_, deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_3_, deliveryno1_.id as id1_6_3_, deliveryno1_.id as id1_6_0_, deliveryno1_.version as version2_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_u as date_u3_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_c as date_c4_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_d as date_d5_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_u as idUser_11_6_0_, deliveryno1_.endTime as endTime8_6_0_, deliveryno1_.init as init9_6_0_, deliveryno1_.initTime as initTim10_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUserAux as idUserA13_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idWork as idWork14_6_0_ from a_deliveryNoteType deliveryno0_ left outer join t_deliveryNote deliveryno1_ on deliveryno0_.id=deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType where deliveryno0_.id=?
19:35:31,759 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_1_, lines0_.version as version2_7_1_, lines0_.amount as amount3_7_1_, lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_1_, lines0_.description as descript4_7_1_ from t_deliveryNoteLine lines0_ where lines0_.idDeliveryNote=?
19:35:31,767 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_1_, lines0_.version as version2_7_1_, lines0_.amount as amount3_7_1_, lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_1_, lines0_.description as descript4_7_1_ from t_deliveryNoteLine lines0_ where lines0_.idDeliveryNote=?
19:35:31,775 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_7_0_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_7_0_, deliveryno0_.amount as amount3_7_0_, deliveryno0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, deliveryno0_.description as descript4_7_0_ from t_deliveryNoteLine deliveryno0_ where deliveryno0_.id=?
19:35:31,785 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_7_0_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_7_0_, deliveryno0_.amount as amount3_7_0_, deliveryno0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, deliveryno0_.description as descript4_7_0_ from t_deliveryNoteLine deliveryno0_ where deliveryno0_.id=?
19:35:31,795 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_1_, lines0_.version as version2_7_1_, lines0_.amount as amount3_7_1_, lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_1_, lines0_.description as descript4_7_1_ from t_deliveryNoteLine lines0_ where lines0_.idDeliveryNote=?
19:35:31,808 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_0_, lines0_.id as id1_7_1_, lines0_.version as version2_7_1_, lines0_.amount as amount3_7_1_, lines0_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_1_, lines0_.description as descript4_7_1_ from t_deliveryNoteLine lines0_ where lines0_.idDeliveryNote=?
19:35:31,816 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_6_1_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_u as date_u3_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_c as date_c4_6_1_, deliveryno0_.date_d as date_d5_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUser_u as idUser_11_6_1_, deliveryno0_.endTime as endTime8_6_1_, deliveryno0_.init as init9_6_1_, deliveryno0_.initTime as initTim10_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idUserAux as idUserA13_6_1_, deliveryno0_.idWork as idWork14_6_1_, lines1_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_3_, lines1_.id as id1_7_3_, lines1_.id as id1_7_0_, lines1_.version as version2_7_0_, lines1_.amount as amount3_7_0_, lines1_.idDeliveryNote as idDelive5_7_0_, lines1_.description as descript4_7_0_ from t_deliveryNote deliveryno0_ left outer join t_deliveryNoteLine lines1_ on deliveryno0_.id=lines1_.idDeliveryNote where deliveryno0_.id=?
19:35:31,840 INFO  [stdout](71): Hibernate: select deliveryno0_.id as id1_0_1_, deliveryno0_.version as version2_0_1_, deliveryno0_.name as name3_0_1_, deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_3_, deliveryno1_.id as id1_6_3_, deliveryno1_.id as id1_6_0_, deliveryno1_.version as version2_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_u as date_u3_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_c as date_c4_6_0_, deliveryno1_.date_d as date_d5_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_c as idUser_c6_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_d as idUser_d7_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUser_u as idUser_11_6_0_, deliveryno1_.endTime as endTime8_6_0_, deliveryno1_.init as init9_6_0_, deliveryno1_.initTime as initTim10_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType as idDeliv12_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idUserAux as idUserA13_6_0_, deliveryno1_.idWork as idWork14_6_0_ from a_deliveryNoteType deliveryno0_ left outer join t_deliveryNote deliveryno1_ on deliveryno0_.id=deliveryno1_.idDeliveryNoteType where deliveryno0_.id=?
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your `DeliveryNote` class implements the `equals` (and as a result `hashcode`) method.  If it doesn't, then there's a good chance `deliveryNotes.remove(note);` will do nothing.

If you're already doing this (I can't tell from the question) and using the `work` relationship in the `equals` method, then setting the `Work` field to `null` before calling the `remove` changes the state of the object and causes `equals` to return false.  Simply set the relationship to `null` after removing it from the collection.

Comment: equals is overridden and remove does it job. I do the same to other collection and it works. It is a kind of strange case.

Comment: Strange.  This is a long shot, but can you try removing the `note.setWork(null);` call?  It shouldn't be required since the entity is about to be deleted anyway.

Comment: I tried without note.setWork(null) and same result. I'll keep on searching what is this issue.

Comment: Post an answer when you get a result, it's certainly stumped me! good luck :)